# How to get multiple selectonemenu value in p:ajax function and display data

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces and i need to show total count of applicant depending on the select box that has been choose by the candidate. As i am new to primefaces a dont now how to pass the parameter .  i am giving my code bellow.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="4" columnClasses="control-label">

    <h:outputText
        value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.personal.proposeofexam']}" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="propExam" value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.examination}" 
                     converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" editable="false"
                     required="true" label="Examination Applied For" styleClass="dropdownWidth">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="---Select One---" itemValue="0" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.testExamNames}" var="test" itemLabel="#{test.name}" itemValue="#{test}" />

    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputText value="Select Degree Category :" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="degreeList"
                     value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.degree}" editable="false"
                     converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true"
                     label="Please Select degree" styleClass="dropdownWidth">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select One---" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.degreeNames}"
                       var="degree" itemLabel="#{degree.name}" itemValue="#{degree}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>


    <h:outputText value="Center of Examination :"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="centerId" value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.center}" editable="false" 
                     converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true" label="Please select Center"
                     styleClass="dropdownWidth">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select One---"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.centerNames}" var="center" 
                       itemLabel="#{center.name}" itemValue="#{center}"/>
        <p:ajax   listener="#{issueAdmitCardBean.readVenuefromCenter(issueAdmitCardBean.center.id)}" update="venueNames"  />
        <p:ajax   listener="#{issueAdmitCardBean.selectContByid(issueAdmitCardBean.center.id,issueAdmitCardBean.examname.id,issueAdmitCardBean.degree.id)}" update="venueNames"  />
    </p:selectOneMenu>


    <h:outputText value="Total No. of Candidates Under this Category :"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.getTotalNoofCandidates}"/>
```

plz help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

There is a problem for me. i have using my ajax button at the last selectone menu button. but i have to change it as if a change a value in my first selectone menu my ajax should work. my problem is if am using same method here i will get null pointer exception. please help me how can i change it.

Comment: please give any suggetion

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do. You want to update some bean value when user selects something in `selectOneMenu`? Which one, the third one (centerId)?

Comment: i need centerId,degreeId,examId  perameter to pass in my second ajax and it will show my total applicant count .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this for your second `<p:ajax>`

```
<p:ajax listener="#{issueAdmitCardBean.selectContByid(issueAdmitCardBean.center.id,issueAdmitCardBean.examination.id,issueAdmitCardBean.degree.id)}" update="venueNames" process="propExam degreeList centerId"/>
```